# In R how do I access the new coordinates after a transform for mapping in geom_point?

Tags: r, mapping, overlay, projection

I have maps I'd like to overlay - a map of Canada, a map of interactions and a population density map. Orthographic looks better so I transform each set of coordinates like this:

```
mycanada <- ne_states(country = 'canada', returnclass="sf")
mycanada1 <- st_transform(mycanada, crs= "+proj=ortho +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-100")

adtransformed <- ad%>% st_as_sf(coords = c('lg', 'lt'), crs=4326)
adtransformed2 <- st_transform(adtransformed, crs ="+proj=ortho +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-100")

pop <- data.frame(CanPop2021)
pop2 <- pop%>% st_as_sf(coords = c('DARPLONG_ADLONG', 'DARPLAT_ADLAT'), crs = 4326)
pop3 <- st_transform(pop2, crs ="+proj=ortho +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-100")
```

After I transform everything I want overlay all three like this:

```
ggplot(data = mycanada1) +
  geom_sf(color="gray80", fill="gray30") +
  geom_sf(data=adtransformed2, size = 2, color = "yellow", alpha = 0.75)+
  
  geom_point(data = pop3,mapping = aes(x, y, color=log(pop$DBPOP2021_IDPOP2021), alpha=exp(pop$DBPOP2021_IDPOP2021)))+
   scale_colour_gradientn(colours=heat.colors(7),
                         breaks = log(c(1, 10, 100, 1000)),
                         labels = c(1, 10, 100, 1000),
                         name = "Pop Density")+
  
  
  
    coord_sf(crs = '+proj=ortho +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-100',
           xlim = c(3250000, -2100000), ylim = c(-780000, 2150000),
           expand = FALSE)
```

The pop3 table looks like:

| FEDNAME_CEFNOM | CDUID_DRIDU | DBPOP2021_IDPOP2021 | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| St. John's S.. | 1001 | 160 | c(3167031.37857608, 785345.940093255) |

I think my problem is in accessing the new x and y values in the aes statement in geom_point. At least I'm currently getting 'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found. I know I probably need to reference it but I don't know how (same for y if I were to figure this out, I assume).

The original table for pop had 'DARPLAY_ADLAT' and 'DARPLONG_ADLONG' for latitude and longitude.

Works fine without the geom_point bit, the problem is Canada is so big I need to show that we have interactions where the people are (which is why I'm trying to overlay the population density).

Comment: It looks like pop3 is also an sf object. Why not add it as a `geom_sf` layer instead of `geom_point`? If it only contains points, these will be drawn as points.

Comment: This worked just fine - didn't have to reference the aes because geom_sf assumes by default that the positions are in the geometry field - worked great.